# Get the desired row of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am using DataGrid in my project. All columns are textblocks besides one of them which is combobox

```
private void LevelsBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
        ComboBoxItem selectedItem = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox.SelectedItem;
        string x = selectedItem.Content.ToString();
    }
```

x is the value of combobox. Now I need the raw where the value of combobox is selected.

Comment: int row = yourdatagrid.[SelectedIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.selectedindex?view=netframework-4.8);

Comment: @SajithSageer Thank you very much. You helped me.)))